# Firebaseapperror: failed to parse private key: error: invalid pem formatted message

Tags: node.js, parsing, environment-variables, firebase-admin, multiline

I got this error `firebaseapperror: failed to parse private key: error: invalid pem formatted message` when I pushed my nodejs app to heroku.

I had my environment variables all set like this

```
# .env file
    
project_id=project_id
private_key='-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- ... ------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
client_email=client_email
```

And accessed them like so:

```
export const sa = {
    privateKey: process.env.private_key,
    projectId: process.env.project_id,
    clientEmail: process.env.client_email
};
```

On my local everything worked fine, but on production (heroku) I got the error mentioned above. The private key is a multiline environment variable and it couldn't be parsed.

Please, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 16):

**The Fix**

How I fixed this was through a post I saw online: [How to Store a Long, Multi-line Private Key in an Environment Variable](https://dev.to/cfofiu/how-to-store-a-long-private-key-in-vercel-s-environment-variables-46f5)

Follow the step and you should fix this as well.

**Brief summary of the post is this:**

Store the long, multi-line key as a json string like this:

```
# .env file

project_id=project_id
private_key='{"privateKey": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- ... ------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"}'
client_email=client_email
```

Then parse it and destructure the key like this:

```
const { privateKey } = JSON.parse(process.env.private_key);

export const sa = {
    privateKey,
    projectId: process.env.project_id,
    clientEmail: process.env.client_email
};
```

This would work on local, but **on production** (heroku) you will get a **parse error** because of the **single quote** before and after the very key in question. Therefore, **remove the single quotes** before and after the key **in your production env variable**. I also **tried without** the **single quote** on local and **it worked**.

> Extra Benefit

**Extra Benefit with this Method**

From this, you could even store the entire environment variables as one object like this

```
# .env file

sa='{"privateKey": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- ... ------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "clientEmail": "client_email", "projectId": "project_id"}'
```

Then access it like this:

```
export const sa = JSON.parse(process.env.sa);
```

That's it.

*Reminder: remember what I said about **single quote***!

Comment: Also check out [How to Store a Long, Multi-line Private Key in an Environment Variable](https://dev.to/cfofiu/how-to-store-a-long-private-key-in-vercel-s-environment-variables-46f5)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use single/double quotes to store private key and then escape the \n characters while consuming

## .env file

```
project_id=project_id
private_key=-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- ... ------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
client_email=client_email
```

Code-

```
const CERT = process?.env?.private_key?.replace(
  /\\n/g,
 '\n',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, getting rid of single/double quotes around `private_key` solved it in my case. You can set private key in your prod env variables as:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1):

The most consistent result for me was to transform the json to base64 string and then `JSON.parse(Buffer.from(process.env.CERT, 'base64').toString())`

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use the private key by entering it in Vercel for example,
what worked for me is remove all \n and quotes from your private key string.
You don't need to `JSON.parse`!

If you have `.env`

```
PRIVATE_KEY ="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

You will notice there are a whole bunch of \n that does not seem necessary.
In fact they are not, so remove them all
`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`

Remove the double quotes too.

Add them to Vercel environment variables as a new variable.

use it like this.

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be \n not \n.

Not this

```
6","private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIEv
```

should be this

```
6","private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEv
```

There will be many \n in RSA key, check for more